# How can I set a notification on a specific day and specific time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, notifications

I want to make a notification to appear on a specific date at a specific time, as I wrote in the title.
Now my alerts come in 10 seconds after pressing the button. If I need to set a specific date, do I need to do that as well? I need convert the date into milliseconds and give this parameter?
Here's my code:

```
package com.example.timeman;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
public class ReminderBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notify")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_close_24)
            .setContentTitle("Salamabuliy")
            .setContentText("TextNotif")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            ;
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    notificationManager.notify(200, builder.build());
}
```

}

And OnClick Method:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReminderBroadcast.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            long timeAtButtonClick = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long tenSecondsInMillis = 1000*10;

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeAtButtonClick + tenSecondsInMillis, pendingIntent);
            //displayNotification();
            OpenThis(view);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to find the duration in millis between now and the date you want it to appear on. For example;

```java
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

LocalDateTime end = now.plusSeconds(10); // end date can be specific, this is an example

Duration difference = Duration.between(now, end);

long differenceMillis = difference.toMillis();
```

Comment: `System.out.println(differenceMillis);` will always give you `10000`. If this is what you intended to have, it's better to use `final long differenceMillis = 10000L;`

Comment: The end date is intended to be dynamic, the example I provided was not specifically because it's an example. The user would provide the end date themselves using whatever mechanism they have to do so.

Comment: Jason - I've always liked your answers and especially your attitude. The only thing that I wanted to highlight in my comment is that out of the four lines in your answer, the last two are unnecessary. Since you are adding `10 seconds` to `now` to get `end`, there is no need to calculate the difference (which will always be 10 seconds).

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that. I didn't mean to come off as rude I just wanted to clarify, I could definitely be misunderstanding your point so I apologize. Let me try to explain again with a bit more context and a better example. If the user provided the `end` as a LocalDateTime that is in the future, for example `08/21/2020 00:01:00`, then we have no idea what the duration between now and `end` is, so we use a Duration. I only used `LocalDateTime#plusSeconds` as an example end date but that was likely a poor  and confusing example. I hope this helped clarify.

Comment: Jason: `I didn't mean to come off as rude I just wanted to clarify` - I've mentioned a couple of times earlier that you have a heart of gold. No, your comment was not rude at all. It's all clear...wish you a good day!

Comment: Awesome man, thank you! I hope you have a good day too man, I hope to see you around. I've definitely seen you around as well! I'm sure I've learned a thing or two from ya.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Instant#toEpochMilli()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) and [`Instant#plusSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#plusSeconds-long-) as shown below:

```
import java.time.Instant;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now.toEpochMilli());

        // After 10 seconds
        Instant after10SecFromNow = now.plusSeconds(10);
        long millisAfter10Sec = after10SecFromNow.toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println(millisAfter10Sec);

        // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, millisAfter10Sec, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1597837345043
1597837355043
```

Learn more about `java.time`<sup>*</sup>, [the modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html), from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Intant.now() requires min API 26. Just for future watchers